# What is the correct way to display a HTML file downloaded and saved in the file system using codename one?

Tags: html, browser, filesystems, storage, codenameone

What is the correct way to display a HTML file downloaded and saved in the file system? I am able to download and save the html page in the .cn1 folder on Simulator but it doesn't display. I tested using the Page.html sample file found in the old Kitchen Sink demo.

Also, how can I use hardcoded paths like file:///storage/emulated/0/Folder/Page.html instead? I have tried but nothing appears in common folders in the phone e.g. the Android folder. Below is what I have done so far!

```
`Form fm_brw = new Form();` 
`fm_brw.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`

`FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();`
`fs.mkdir(fs.getAppHomePath() + "SampleFolder");`

`Util.downloadUrlToFile("http://somesite.com/Page.html", fs.getAppHomePath() + "SampleFolder/Page.html", true);`

`BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();`
`browser.setURL(fs.getAppHomePath() + "SampleFolder/Page.html);`

`fm_brw.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);` 
`fm_brw.show();`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shai Almog - Happy 2018 and please accept my apologies for the delayed reply. I figured out the reason for the webpage not diplaying... apparently, you have to add the "**file://**" when setting the url i.e. **browser.setURL("file://"+str_homePath+str_filePath);**

If this is not by your design then I can file an RFE.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hardcode paths on phones as those differ even on the same phone for new installs to keep app isolation.

Your approach is correct but I'm assuming the html refers to images and other resources which are now unavailable so the process of downloading an HTML file for offline viewing is more complex as you would need to download all the resources then edit the HTML source to reference local files instead of server files.

Comment: All the resources are available because the HTML is part of a **SCORM** package playable offline for LMS. The particular LMS that we have managed to integrate CN1 to is **Moodle**. 

We have been able to _download_, _unzip_ and _save_ to **FileSystemStorage** the package while maintaining its folder structure and arranging all its content in the correct place. 

The next challenge would b how to play the SCORM files. To do this we need to display the HTML file in the **BrowserComponent** and link to the subfiles from the index via **Frame-sets** and capture data via JS from each HTML file.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that, using the setup above and the old KitchenSink Page.html file for test, the page is blank in both the simulators and on device. browser.getTitle() prints null in both simulator and device. 

For  fs.getAppHomePath() they respectively show:
    `file://home/SampleFolder/Page.html` and
    `/data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp/files/SampleFolder/Page.html`

On simulator, the folder and the file are created in the .cn1 folder but the error below is shown on console:

    Received exception: File not found
    java.lang.Throwable: File not found

Comment: Below is the full error:\n
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.describeError(WebEngine.java:1436)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1375)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1200(WebEngine.java:1253)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1240)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2400)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2244)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFail(Native Method)
at cn.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFail(URLLoader.java:862)

Comment: at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didFail$97(URLLoader.java:845)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: What could I be missing?

Comment: There might be a small issue in the simulator here but on the device this should work. What do you see in DDMS when you run this?