# Unzipping .zip folder with Zipme Library in Codename One

Tags: codenameone, unzip

This is as a followup to the question that I asked here:
[What is the correct way to display a HTML file downloaded and saved in the file system using codename one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052612/what-is-the-correct-way-to-display-a-html-file-downloaded-and-saved-in-the-file/47068118?noredirect=1#comment81165683_47068118)

I am successful to display a html file from a folder using webview. The trick is to add the "**file://**" when setting the url as shown below:

**browser.setURL("file://"+str_homePath+str_filePath);**

If this is not by your design then I can file an RFE. Nonetheless, next I hit an Unzipping challenge which I think might be related to the "**file://**" issue above.

When unzipping a .zip file using the **Zipme cn1lib**, everything extracts OK on simulator but fails on device. I had to root a phone in order to see what exactly is going on. I found that some files are not extracted.

Checking on the DDMS confirmed my findings. Every so often I see this error: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)

Then, when I try to display the index file (which should fail because of the above missing files), I get this error:
I/System.out: showKeyboard false
I/System.out: showKeyboard false
D/WebView: loadUrl=file:///data/user/0/ke.co.imedia.samplefilepath/files/17/rte.html
W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Below is the code I am using to unzip:

```java
try
{
    System.out.println("Finding FILE TO UNZIP: ");
    InputStream zipFile = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("folderName"+".zip");
    //InputStream zipFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(fs.getAppHomePath()+"folderName"+".zip");
    fs.mkdir(fs.getAppHomePath()+"folderName");
    System.out.println("ZIPPED FILE FOUND: ");
    Unzip(zipFile, "/"+ "folderName");
    System.out.println("UNZIPPED SUCCESFULLY");
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Log.p(ex.getMessage(), 0);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above codes calls the following method as copied from the link below, with some edits that I hoped would allow extracting to a folder by checking whether the next entry during the unzipping process is a directory or not.
https://github.com/codenameone/ZipSupport

```java
public void Unzip(InputStream is_zipFile, String str_dirDest) 
 {
    InputStream is;
    try 
    {
        is = is_zipFile;
        ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(is);
        ZipEntry entry;

        // create a buffer to improve copy performance later.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        System.out.println("TRYING TO UZIP: ");

        while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) 
        {
            FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
            String str_name = entry.getName();
            String dir;
            String str_outdir = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
            //FileOutputStream fileoutputstream;
            File newFile = new File(str_outdir, str_name);
            boolean overwrite = false;
            if (str_outdir.length() > 0) 
            {
                str_outdir = str_outdir + "/" + str_dirDest;
            }

            //extractFile(zin, outdir, name);
            String outpath = str_outdir + "/" + entry.getName();
            OutputStream output = null;

            try 
            {
                if (entry.isDirectory()) 
                {

                    fs.mkdir(str_outdir + "/" + str_name);
                    entry = zipStream.getNextEntry();
                    continue;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    File file = new File(str_outdir + File.separator + str_name);
                    File parent = file.getParentFile();
                    if (!parent.exists()) 
                    {
                        parent.mkdirs();
                    }

                }

                System.out.println("UNZIPPING:- " + str_name);
                output = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(outpath);
                int len = 0;
                while ((len = zipStream.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Dialog.show("Unzipping Error!", ""+e, "Ok", null);
            } 
            finally 
            {

                if (output != null) 
                {
                    output.close();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.p(ex.getMessage(), 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: The `file://` prefix should exist already in any standard way of getting the path to a directory or file. Which file isn't found and on which line of the code above?

Comment: the second entry = zipStream.getNextEntry(); should not be there, that definitely causes issues.